# Devise returns 2 errors when only 1 should be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have module `validatable` enabled for my app. On a screen when I am asking for the user's email address for registration, if the email already exists...this is the error I see:

```
We found 2 errors that prevented your account from being created:
Email has already been takenEmail has already been taken
```

This is from the logs:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-21 14:37:41 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zcpDH5U4XkHcYWVHEqrshgmzGiqsZHI9mD6Inrdr8uE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@email.com"}, "commit"=>"Sign Me Up!"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@email.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('abc@email.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1118ms (Views: 290.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

How do I get it from trying to do two checks and just do 1?

Comment: Have you added validate_uniqeness_of :email to your model? If so then it will check the email twice.

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to log in but it wont let me.

I don't do ruby but it looks like you are probably entering in a email that meets the criteria for both of these. Probably only need the 2nd one. Hope this helps!

`User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@email.com' LIMIT 1

User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('abc@email.com') LIMIT 1`

Comment: That doesn't help. Those SQL statements are generated by Rails. I didn't write them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Rails runs separate checks for each validation, so a presence and a uniqueness validator will result in two checks.  If you want to avoid the redundant error messages, you can do something like the below and only output unique error messages:

```
#error_explanation
  .alert.alert-error
    Please correct the following #{pluralize(object.errors.full_messages.uniq.size, "error")}:
   %ul
   - object.errors.full_messages.uniq.each do |msg|
     %li #{msg}
```